# How to handle nested menu in knockout viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs in my project. I have a scenario where I have to create a nested menu in my viewmodel, which I did like this:

```
self.menu = [
    { 
         name: 'Services', 
         sub: [{ name: 'Service-A' }, { name: 'Service-B' }] 
    },
    // etc
];

self.chosenMenu = ko.observable();

self.goToMenu = function (main, sub) {

    var selectedMenu = {
        main: main,
        sub: sub
    };

    self.chosenMenu(selectedMenu);
};
```

My View:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav menuitems col-md-8" data-bind="foreach: menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span data-bind="text: name"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: sub">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: name, 
                   click: function() { $root.goToMenu($parent, $data); }">
                </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I feel that this approach of creating nested menu is not good, because suppose if I want to go on any menu item programmatically then with his approach it is not possible?

Can anybody please suggest me the good approach to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Looks like you already select menu items programmatically: `$root.goToMenu($parent, $data);`
You may also consider adding some unique id to each menu item (if they don't already have one). That might simplify searching and selecting menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each menu item has a *unique* identifier. For the example data you've given `name` will suffice, but you may have to add a `fullPath` property to menu item view models.

Your `goToMenu` function can now take just one parameter: `uniqueMenuIdentifier`, and recurse through all menu items to find the correct one, like this:

```
function findMenuItem(menuList, uniqueMenuIdentifier) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        if (menuList[i].name === uniqueMenuIdentifier) {
            return menuList[i];
        }
        if (!!menuList[i].sub) {
            var subItem = findMenuItem(menuList[i].sub, uniqueMenuIdentifier);
            if (!!subItem) {
                return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

self.goToMenu = function (menuItem) {
    var uniqueMenuIdentifier = menuItem.name;
    var item = findMenuItem(self.menu, uniqueMenuIdentifier);
    self.chosenMenu(item);
}
```

This allows for a much simpler binding in the anchor tag:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text: name, click: $root.goToMenu">
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qb2u/) for a demo.

From this you can also guess that it's even possible to set the `chosenMenu` directly:

```
// No longer needed:
//function findMenuItem(menuList, uniqueMenuIdentifier) { }

self.goToMenu = function (menuItem) {
    self.chosenMenu(menuItem);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qb2u/1/) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar scenario yesterday. You can have a look at my solution on
[Is there any knockout plugin for showing a nested context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387631/is-there-any-knockout-plugin-for-showing-a-nested-context-menu). The main point is that I've used the template binding to be able to construct a hierarchical menu of any depth.