# Is there any knockout plugin for showing a nested context menu?

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

Is there any knockout plugin for showing a nested context menu?

My specific need is to show a contextmenu for list items, that has a "SendTo" menuitem and the possible subItems have to be set at runtime.

Comment: Please be aware that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the apparent lack of suitable plugins I went for the more direct Knockout approach. I'm sure the code can be more elegantly packed in a custom binding but this is the solution I came up with, if anyone would need something similar. In my case the menu is build each time it's opened because it makes sense in my usecase. I'm sure the code can easily be customized to some other scenarios.

So... The markup:
  `<li data-bind="event: { contextmenu: $root.showSendToMenu }/>` 
is used to show the popup menu, for an item on a right click.
And the markup for the menu itself:

```
@*The send to popup menu*@
<ul class="context-menu" data-bind="visible:contextMenu.activeElement, style:{left:contextMenu.left, top:contextMenu.top}, template: { name: 'menu-item-template', foreach: contextMenu.items }, event: { mouseleave: contextMenu.contextMouseLeave }"></ul>

@*Template for a menu item*@
<script type="text/html" id="menu-item-template">
    <li>
        <!-- ko if: children -->
        <span data-bind="text:text"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'menu-item-template', foreach: children }"></ul>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: !children -->
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:text, click:$root.onContextClick"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</script>
```

And in the viewModel, I have the following code (TypeScript):

```
contextMenu = { activeElement: ko.observable(null), left: ko.observable('0px'), top: ko.observable('200px'), items: ko.observableArray(<MenuItem[]>[]), contextMouseLeave : () => { this.contextMenu.activeElement(null); } };

    showSendToMenu = (item, event) => {

        //Set menu position
        this.contextMenu.left(event.pageX + 'px');
        this.contextMenu.top(event.pageY + 'px');

        //Build the menu
        var lines = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.prodLines().length; i++) {
            var line = this.prodLines()[i];

            if (line.lists().length > 0) {
                var lists = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < line.lists().length; j++) {
                    var list = line.lists()[j];
                    lists.push(new MenuItem(list.name(), null, list));
                }
                lines.push(new MenuItem(line.name + "->", lists, line));
            }
        }

        var items = [new MenuItem("SendTo ->", lines)];

        //Set the menu
        this.contextMenu.items(items);
        this.contextMenu.activeElement(item);
    }


    onContextClick = (menuItem: MenuItem) => {
        var sendToList = menuItem.tag;
        var item = this.contextMenu.activeElement();
        this.dropToList(item, sendToList);
        //Hide the menu
        this.contextMenu.activeElement(null);
    }
```

And lastly, I used this piece of css to make the menu behave menu-like:

```
.context-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  min-width:100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.context-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1031;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display:none;
  left:98px;
  min-width:100px;
  top:-1px;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.context-menu li {
  position:relative;
}

.context-menu li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

.context-menu li {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333333;
}
.context-menu ul > li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I hope this will help someone